# SimpleXMLElement expand to repeated values in array

Tags: php, simplexml

Please help me.. I spent a lot of time on it and I think I ran out of ideas.

I have that code for function array_to_xml:

```
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                if( is_array($value)) {
                    if (!empty($value["@attributes"])) {
                            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key, $value["@value"]);
                            foreach ($value["@attributes"] as $key1 => $val1) {
                                $subnode->addAttribute($key1, $val1);
                            }
                    } else if ($key == "@value") {
                        foreach ($value as $attr => $attrVal) {
                            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild("$attr", $attrVal);
                            array_to_xml($attrVal, $subnode);
                        }
                    } else {
                            if (!empty($value) and $key != "kontakt") {
                                    $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                                    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                                    
                            } else if (!empty($value) and $key == "kontakt") {
                                        $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                                        array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                            };  
                    }
                } else {
                        $xml_data->addChild("$key",$value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When it hits the "contact" attribute, it creates the following structure:

```
<kontakt>
<1 typ="email">abc@abc.pl</1>
<2 typ="telefon">3123453141</2>
</kontakt>
```

How should the function be changed so that its result would be the structure shown below?

```
<kontakt typ="email">abc@abc.pl</kontakt>
<kontakt typ="telefon">3123453141</kontakt>
```

The array:

```
"kontakt"=>[ 
1=>[
     '@value' => 'abc@abc.pl',
     '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'email'],
    ],
2=>[
     '@value' => '3123453141',
     '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'telefon'],
            ],
          ],
```

That's the only thing I'm missing for happiness ;)

Answer (score 0):

something like that (i´ve rewritten your function):

```
<?php

function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
          foreach($value as $innerkey => $innervalue) {
            $v = $innervalue['@value'];
            $t = "";
            if(isset($innervalue['@attributes']['typ'])) {
                $t = $innervalue['@attributes']['typ'];  
            }
            $kontakt = $xml_data->addChild('kontakt', $v);
            $kontakt->addAttribute('typ', $t);
          }
        }
    }

$data = array("kontakt"=>[ 
1=>[
     '@value' => 'abc@abc.pl',
     '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'email'],
    ],
2=>[
     '@value' => '3123453141',
     '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'telefon'],
            ],
          ]
);
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<test></test>') ;
array_to_xml($data,$xml_data);
echo $xml_data->asXML();
```

results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test><kontakt typ="email">abc@abc.pl</kontakt><kontakt typ="telefon">3123453141</kontakt></test>
```

playground: https://3v4l.org/Qo9uaU#v7.0.33

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//the array
$data = array(
"kontakt"=>[ 
    1=>[
       '@value' => 'abc@abc.pl',
       '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'email'],
    ],
    2=>[
     '@value' => '3123453141',
     '@attributes' => ['typ' => 'telefon'],
    ],
 ]);

 //call to function
 $xml = array_to_xml($data);
 show($xml);

//function to convert the array to xml
function array_to_xml( $data) {
$xml = '';
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
                $xml .= '<kontakt typ="'.$value1['@attributes']['typ'].'">';
                $xml .= $value1['@value'].'</kontakt>'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        return $xml;
}

 //function to show it in xml form
 function show($data){
 echo '<pre>';
 echo nl2br(str_replace('<', '&lt;', $data));
 echo '</pre>';

 }
?>
```

May this will help you. You can configure in case of multiple array. The above function will work in case of the provided string.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the recursive function it can help to line-out which cases there are in the data. I found three, and all what is needed to identify them is the *key* that is always string (for the recursive traversal):

1. key is @value -> the elements' node-value
2. key is @attributes -> the elements' attributes key/value map
3. key is the name of child elements -> list of children to add

Only the third case traverses into child nodes.

```php
function array_to_xml(array $array, SimpleXMLElement $xml): void
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === '@value') {
            $xml[0] = $value;
        } elseif ($key === '@attributes') {
            foreach ($value as $name => $item) {
                $xml->addAttribute($name, $item);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($value as $item) {
                array_to_xml($item, $xml->addChild($key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not only far less code, the main difference is that the function operates on the element itself; it doesn't fetch the `$key` only to add it later, in the `else` case it adds it directly and passes the new child with the array.

The recursion is not scattered at mutliple places, but at a single one.

---

SimpleXMLElement itself can also be used to give each node actual method(s) and these automatically propagate over the whole document. Here an ad-hoc example:

```php
(new class ('<test/>') extends SimpleXMLElement {
    public function add(array $array): self
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) match ($key) {
            '@value' => $this[0] = $value,
            '@attributes' => array_map($this->addAttribute(...), array_keys($value), $value),
            default => array_map(fn ($child) => $this->addChild($key)?->add($child), $value),
        };
        return $this;
    }
})->add($array)->asXML('php://output');
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <test><kontakt typ="email">abc@abc.pl</kontakt><kontakt typ="telefon">3123453141</kontakt></test>
```

The result is the same, one benefit could the that you don't need to think that much passing `$xml` around.